# How to migrate OS X user from client to server?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I've recently acquired a mac mini server. Would like to migrate my existing (regular OS X) account to the server. I've created a user with same short name on the server side, but can't use it from my client for some reason.

Also it is not clear how to add a machine to Workgroup Manager. Would you have a good resource/article to read to find out how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the same situation as you.  Here is the question I asked here, with some partial answers that I found: [How to migrate a user from OS X 10.4 to OS X Server 10.6?](https://serverfault.com/questions/118311/how-to-migrate-a-user-from-os-x-10-4-to-os-x-server-10-6)

Comment: I saw this question, but thought it wouldn't be related (since I'm going from 10.6 client -> 10.6 server). I will read all the answers again however :)

Comment: While your question is indeed different, the client -> server part is common.  Coming from an older system adds the problem of data formats that have changed of evolved, in particular (iCal,…).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, are you asking about using the network home folder on your client computer? If so, have you set up the network home folder correctly AND set the client Mac to use the OS X Server's OpenDirectory for authentication/login?

As for the second question, do read the manuals. They are terse and incomplete, but still essential.

Here is a [tutorial](http://infinitysend.net/2008/02/01/workgroup-manager-a-step-by-step-guide-to-common-mac-os-x-server-tasks/) that will get you started:

Comment: I've read a few tutorials (mostly from http://www.makemacwork.com/), but none of the ones I've read help with promoting users to the server, and adding new computers. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I have a pretty useful server already (thanks to all the tutorials and docs I've read:). Server is running just fine svn, httpd, afp, dns, dhcp, mysql. The next stumble for me is specifically creating profiles server side for existing users (on current clients), and adding computers in Workgroup Manager.